Can Azure Logic App SQL trigger compare values in deleted and inserted tables
Can Azure Logic App SQL trigger compare value in deleted and inserted tables in the same manner as a SQL server trigger?
For example, say I'm updating stock prices and I want the trigger to run the workflow when stock price increases by more than 25%
In a SQL server trigger I would set this condition:
Inserted.StockPrice > 1.25 * Deleted.StockPrice
Is there anything similar in Logic App SQL trigger?
Have Googled around OData filters but could find anything relevant.
